# Installing QGIS in virtual environment?

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I have a virtual environment, `(my-virtualenv) bash-3.2$`, running with python 3.6.5 set up using `pyenv`.

I installed the modules listed on the readme (owslib, PyYaml, psycopg2, jinja2, pygments, numpy, plotly). My system has python 2.7 and python 3.7 outside the virtual environment.

How do I install QGIS just within the virt environment?